# wx python detect if user didn't intruct for 5min then do something

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

this is a simple code i am using WX python, i want if user didn't instruct within 1 min it will do something.

```
import wx    
class QuestAsk(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(400, 100),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |
                                wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN,
                          title="Question")
        mainwindows = wx.Panel(self)
        mysizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(mainwindows, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size=(100, 30))
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.StatNow)
        mysizer.Add(self.txt, 15, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainwindows.SetSizer(mysizer)
        self.Show()
    def StatNow(self, event):
        go = self.txt.GetValue()
        go = go.lower()
        link = go.split()
        self.txt.Clear()
        self.txt.SetValue(go)
        if go.startswith(''):
            try:
               #request
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(True)
    frame = QuestAsk()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: On StackExchange, when someone gives you a good answer you should, please, mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing that is to add a `wx.Timer`, like this:

```
import wx
class QuestAsk(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(400, 100),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |
                                wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN,
                          title="Question")
        mainwindows = wx.Panel(self)
        mysizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(mainwindows, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size=(100, 30))
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.StatNow)

        # Add a timer
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(60000)

        mysizer.Add(self.txt, 15, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainwindows.SetSizer(mysizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        print ("Timeout! Please input something")
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.timer.Start(60000)

    def StatNow(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        go = self.txt.GetValue()
        go = go.lower()
        link = go.split()
        self.txt.Clear()
        self.txt.SetValue(go)
        if go.startswith(' '):
            try:
               print ("Go is empty")
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
        self.timer.Start(60000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(True)
    frame = QuestAsk()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: The timer works in milliseconds. I have set the timer at 1 Minute

Edit to cater for key pressed restarting the timer.
The instruction to do something, logically, only occurs once the user has committed the answer i.e. pressed enter. However, if you wish to use the timer in between key depressions, then simply make use of the `EVT_TEXT` event and bind it to a function that restarts the timer.

```
import wx
class QuestAsk(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,
                          pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(400, 100),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |
                                wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN,
                          title="Question")
        mainwindows = wx.Panel(self)
        mysizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(mainwindows, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size=(100, 30))
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.StatNow)
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.CharNow)

        # Add a timer
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(10000)

        mysizer.Add(self.txt, 15, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainwindows.SetSizer(mysizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        self.timer.Stop()
        wx.MessageBox('Please input something and press enter', 'Timeout', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        self.timer.Start(10000)

    def CharNow(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.timer.Start(10000)

    def StatNow(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        go = self.txt.GetValue()
        go = go.lower()
        link = go.split()
        self.txt.SetValue(go)
        if go.startswith(' '):
            wx.MessageBox('Input is Empty. Please input something and press enter', 'Timeout', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
        self.timer.Start(10000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(True)
    frame = QuestAsk()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: I have set the timer at 10 seconds for testing.

Comment: thanks @Rolf of Saxony for help,
problem is that when typing it still triggering the function OnTimer() and that wasn't my goal.

Comment: @AlfredGeorge What is your "goal"? The timer is stopped once you press enter. It then starts again, assuming another input. If you wish it to stop permanently after the initial input, just remove the `Start` in `StatNow`. If you wish the timer to only act once, don't restart it in `Ontimer`

Comment: my goal is too use module like msvcrt to detect keyboard and of course time
if my input is empty for 5min, trigger a function but if  any key is pressed then cuts the timer function and starts again.

Comment: @AlfredGeorge See the second solution in my edited answer

Comment: Thanks @Rolf of Saxony,
i get the picture thanks alot for helping